# Display price and stock status in dropdown variation attribute options of Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dropdown, product-variations

On woocommerce on my variable products each variation has specific price.

How can I display the variation price and stock status in the attribute dropdown options?

[image: screenshot of variation dropdown]

Answer (score 4):

> **Note:** This only works when there is ONLY ONE dropdown select field (so one attribute for the variations set in the variable product). With multiple attributes (so multiple dropdown select fields) it displays something that can be wrong depending on the variations stock status attributes **terms combination**.

The following code will display the variation price and stock status in a unique dropdown variation attribute options:

```
// Utility function to get the price or the stock status of a variation from it's attribute value
function get_variation_price_stock_string( $product, $name, $term_slug ){
    foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
        if($variation['attributes'][$name] == $term_slug ){
            $stock_status = $variation['is_in_stock'] == 1 ? __('In stock') : __('Out of stock');
            return ' (' . strip_tags( $variation['price_html'] ) . ') ' . $stock_status;
        }
    }
}

// Add the price and stock status to the dropdown options items.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'show_stock_status_in_dropdown', 10, 2);
function show_stock_status_in_dropdown( $html, $args ) {
    // Only if there is a unique variation attribute (one dropdown)
    if( sizeof($args['product']->get_variation_attributes()) == 1 ) :

    $options               = $args['options'];
    $product               = $args['product'];
    $attribute             = $args['attribute'];
    $name                  = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $id                    = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $class                 = $args['class'];
    $show_option_none      = $args['show_option_none'] ? true : false;
    $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' );

    if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
        $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
    }

    $html = '<select id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" data-show_option_none="' . ( $show_option_none ? 'yes' : 'no' ) . '">';
    $html .= '<option value="">' . esc_html( $show_option_none_text ) . '</option>';

    if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
        if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {
            $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {
                    // Get the price and stock status
                    $price_stock_html = get_variation_price_stock_string( $product, $name, $term->slug );
                    // Insert the price and stock status
                    $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . $price_stock_html  ) . '</option>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                $selected = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? selected( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : selected( $args['selected'], $option, false );
                // Get the price and stock status
                $price_stock_html = get_variation_price_stock_string( $product, $name, $term->slug );
                // Insert the price and stock status
                $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" ' . $selected . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) . $price_stock_html ) . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    $html .= '</select>';

    endif;

    return $html;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

[image]

Based on:

- [Add the variation price to variable product dropdown item names in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922257/add-the-variation-price-to-variable-product-dropdown-item-names-in-woocommerce/52922993#52922993)
- [How to add variation stock status to Woocommerce product variation dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180058/how-to-add-variation-stock-status-to-woocommerce-product-variation-dropdown/47189725#47189725)

Comment: Thanks Loic, This works brilliantly. Is there a way to stripe "including GST" (the tax text) off the price?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1mNJ.jpg)[price and stock status in dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1mNJ.jpg)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1mNJ.jpg): https://i.**strong text**stack.imgur.com/yvBUH.jpg

---

Thank you very much for this (very fast) reply. I use Flatsome theme and it works great.
As a additional question:
Is there a chance to convert "In Stock" into "Verfügbar / in Stock" and 
Out of Stock into "Ausverkauft / Out of Stock"?
We have customers from Germany and other EU-countries; most of them will understand. But my older customer from Germany will face problems if I am not able to provide some short words in german.
Once again; thank you for your work.
ct