# Show price in dropdown menu for woocommerce variations

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an up to date WordPress site. I want to show the variation price in the drop-down menu.

The site only has one type of variation.

I have tried to use this:  [Add the variation price to variable product dropdown item names in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922257/add-the-variation-price-to-variable-product-dropdown-item-names-in-woocommerce/56021576#56021576)

But its just shows a few ... (dots) but no price

Any help would be great.

I was trying this code:

```
    // Utility function to get the price of a variation from it's attribute 
     value
     function get_the_variation_price_html( $product, $name, $term_slug ){
    foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
        if($variation['attributes'][$name] == $term_slug ){
            return strip_tags( $variation['price_html'] );
        }`enter code here`
    }
    }

// Add the price  to the dropdown options items.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'show_price_in_attribute_dropdown', 10, 2);
function show_price_in_attribute_dropdown( $html, $args ) {
    // Only if there is a unique variation attribute (one dropdown)
    if( sizeof($args['product']->get_variation_attributes()) == 1 ) :

    $options               = $args['options'];
    $product               = $args['product'];
    $attribute             = $args['attribute'];
    $name                  = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $id                    = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $class                 = $args['class'];
    $show_option_none      = $args['show_option_none'] ? true : false;
    $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' );

    if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
        $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
    }

    $html = '<select id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" data-show_option_none="' . ( $show_option_none ? 'yes' : 'no' ) . '">';
    $html .= '<option value="">' . esc_html( $show_option_none_text ) . '</option>';

    if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
        if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {
            $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {
                    // Get and inserting the price
                    $price_html = get_the_variation_price_html( $product, $name, $term->slug );
                    $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . ' ::: ' . $price_html ) . '</option>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                $selected = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? selected( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : selected( $args['selected'], $option, false );
                // Get and inserting the price
                $price_html = get_the_variation_price_html( $product, $name, $term->slug );
                $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" ' . $selected . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) . ' ::: ' . $price_html ) . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    $html .= '</select>';

    endif;

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Without any code we can't help you...

Comment: I have added it now.. Sorry

Comment: What's the dumped result of `get_the_variation_price_html`?

Comment: I got this code from the link i posted, im not sure how to view that

Comment: Insert a line between `$price_html` and `$html` containing `var_dump($price_html); die();`. You should get some output, just post it here.

Comment: when i add that i this happens....
http://prntscr.com/nlkj6m

Comment: Right click the page and click View Source. This is what you're expecting https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php