# Add the min price difference in WooCommerce variable products attribute dropdown options

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dropdown, product-variations

I have products with multiple attributes allowing for multiple dimensions of variations. I'd like to show the price difference in the dropdown, but it is not comparing the absolute minimum price, for each option.

This is the code I am using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name','display_price_in_variation_option_name');

function display_price_in_variation_option_name( $term ) {
    global $product;
    
if ( empty( $term ) ) {
    return $term;
}
if ( empty( $product->id ) ) {
    return $term;
}

$variation_id = $product->get_children();
$price_min = $product->get_variation_regular_price();

foreach ( $variation_id as $id ) {
    $_product       = new WC_Product_Variation( $id );
    $variation_data = $_product->get_variation_attributes();

    foreach ( $variation_data as $key => $data ) {

        if ( $data == $term ) {
            $html  = $term;
            $price_diff = $_product->get_price() - $price_min;
            $price_html = '';
            if ($price_diff > 0 ) { $price_html = ' (+£' . number_format((float)$price_diff, 2, '.', '') . ')';}
            $html  .= $price_html;
            return $html;
        }
    }
}
return $term;
}
```

However, this is only showing [the minimum price of the current attribute, not the product as a whole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwDHG.png).

[image: the minimum price of the current attribute, not the product as a whole]

I hope this is clear - ideally in the above image for options that do not add cost, $price_html should be blank. The code works perfectly for variations with a single attribute option, but does not work for variations with multiple attribute options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified and optimized, **but it can't work with multiple attribute dropdowns**. It can only work **if there is a unique attribute dropdown** *(see the alternative way after)*.

So this code works **only with one attribute dropdown**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name','display_diff_price_in_attribute_option_name', 10, 4 );
function display_diff_price_in_attribute_option_name( $term_name, $term, $attribute, $product ) {
    if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') || is_admin() ) {
        return $term_name;
    }
    $price_min = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true); // Min price for display

    foreach ( $product->get_children() as $variation_id ) {
        $variation  = wc_get_product($variation_id);
        $term_value = $variation->get_attribute($attribute);

        if ( $term_value == $term_name ) {
            $price_diff = wc_get_price_to_display($variation) - $price_min;

            if ($price_diff > 0 ) {
                $term_name .= ' (+' . strip_tags( wc_price( $price_diff ) ) . ')';
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return $term_name;
}
```

**So you need something different** *(when there is multiple attribute dropdowns)*.

The following code will display the price difference for the select variation, for example at the right of the selected variation price:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'filter_available_variation_attributes', 10, 3 );
function filter_available_variation_attributes( $data, $product, $variation ){
    $price_min  = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true); // Min price for display
    $price_diff = $data['display_price'] - $price_min;

    if ($price_diff > 0 ) {
        $data['price_html'] = '<span class="price">' . $variation->get_price_html() . ' <em>(+' . wc_price( $price_diff ) . ')</em></span>';
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Loic, do you know the reason why it won't work for multiple attribute dropdowns?

Comment: @DanielLewis It simply can't work  **logically**, think about it.

Comment: I am thinking about it - if product 00 is the cheapest combination of attributes, and 11 is the most expensive, why is each attribute dropdown not (00, 01) and (00, 10), but is rather (01,11) and (10,11)? Sorry if that is unclear.

Comment: It's simply something logical about dynamic combinations, see those existing similar threads (which requires to have only one attribute dropdown too): https://stackoverflow.com/a/45041602/3730754 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/52922993/3730754 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/53492111/3730754