# foreach loop is not showing all results (woocommerce variation dropdown)

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to customize the variations dropdown on the product page using the answers here:

[Add the variation price to variable product dropdown item names in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922257/add-the-variation-price-to-variable-product-dropdown-item-names-in-woocommerce)

```
function wiz_rebuild_variation_dropdown( $html, $args ) {


  // Only if there is a unique variation attribute (one dropdown)
  if( sizeof($args['product']->get_variation_attributes()) == 1 ) :

        $options               = $args['options'];
        $product               = $args['product'];
        $attribute             = $args['attribute'];

        $show_option_none      = $args['show_option_none'] ? true : false;
        $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' );

        


        if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
            $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
            $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
        }
        
       
            
        // Build the Select container
        $html = '<select id="something">';
        $html .= '<option value="something">' . esc_html( $show_option_none_text ) . '</option>';
       
        if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {

        
            foreach ( $options as $option ) {

            // print_r($option);

             $html .= '<option value="'. esc_html( $option ) . '">something</option>';

            }

        }  

   
        // Close the Select container
        $html .= '</select>';


    endif; // More than one attributes (multiple pulldowns) - code not executed
    
    return $html;



}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'wiz_rebuild_variation_dropdown', 10, 2);
```

Somehow the dropdown will not show more than one  tag. I have checked the array and there are 4 results (print_r in the foreach). If I comment out the 'Choose an option' option, the first result in the foreach will show, but not the other three. Is something going wrong with appending the $html variable?

I'm getting dizzy from trying :-/
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Cheers,
Mark

btw, this is my first ever post to this awesome platform that saved my life so many times before.
Thanks to all for the great help through the years!

Comment: Maybe you should give those options an actual text content, and not just a value?

Comment: @CBroe Tried it, but no, it didn't help (updated my code above). Thanks though..

Comment: Can you check the generated HTML and see if anything is added in the options.

Comment: @NigelRen Actually! The source shows:

<select id="something"><option value="something">Choose an option</option><option value="Deluxe Single Room">something</option><option value="Deluxe Double Room">something</option><option value="Basic Double Room">something</option><option value="Shared Room">something</option></select>

My inspector and browser show nothing under the first option tag (except the closing select tag. Weird stuff...

Comment: That HTML renders as expected in Chrome and Firefox for me. Perhaps you have some additional JS code running on the page, that manipulates the content of that select field afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe I guess a script replaces the content of the option tags, hiding them. Not quite sure which one. I found that adding class="attached enabled" stops this from happening and results in all options shown. Now to find out where to load those variables dynamically. Thanks for the tip! I'll post a more solid solution when I find it.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what the problem was. Looks like this pulldown will not function without the correct name attribute in the SELECT tag.

by catching that like in the original example (see URL):

`$name = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );`

and adding it to the SELECT:

`name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '"`

the script adds the required class names to the option tags automatically and image/price changes function as well.

Thanks for the tips, guys! Pff.. one step made today :))